# ClassCastException when converting String to Date in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date
>   at avb.Test.main(Test.java:38)
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")

from the code

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String tmp = "2012-03-16 18:58:14.0";
Date MaxCmTimerUpdate = (Date)df.parse(tmp);
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you're casting to java.util.Date in the line `(Date) df.parse(tmp)`? Besides, `DateFormat.parse(String)` already returns a java.util.Date, so there's no need for the casting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you've got an import for `java.sql.Date` (or some other `Date` type), whereas `SimpleDateFormat` parses to a `java.util.Date`. You shouldn't need the cast at all.

You won't be able to cast to a different `Date` type - if you need to create a `java.sql.Date`, you'll have to create a new one *based on* the `java.util.Date`, e.g.

```
Date timerUpdate = new Date(df.parse(tmp).getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you accidentally importing `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`? It's the only reason you would need that cast in there at all.

Damn! Beaten by Jon Skeet AGAIN! Jon, what DO Google pay you for? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

does this work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String tmp = "2012-03-16 18:58:14.0";
java.util.Date maxCmTimerUpdate = df.parse(tmp);
```

if so, the other 2 answers are right.